# Unit testing with generics

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, generics

I have something like:

```
class BackupList : List<Backup> {}
```

and the tests that VS2010 has generated for me look somewhat like:

```
[TestMethod()]
[DeploymentItem("[...].exe")]
public void AddBackupNormal()
{
    SqlServer_Accessor.BackupList ls = new SqlServer_Accessor.BackupList("", "");
    SqlServer_Accessor.Backup bk = new SqlServer_Accessor.Backup();
    ls.Add(bk);
    Assert.IsTrue(ls.Count == 0); // won't compile
    List<SqlServer_Accessor.Backup> x = new List<SqlServer_Accessor.Backup>();
    Assert.IsTrue(x.Count == 1);  // compiles fine
}
```

however, in the above, the .Count reference fails to compile with:

> Error 1   'xxx.SqlServer_Accessor.BackupList'
>   does not contain a definition for 'Count' and no extension method
>   'Count' accepting a first argument of type
>   'xxx.SqlServer_Accessor.BackupList'
>   could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)   C:[...]Tests\SqlServer_BackupListTest.cs

interestingly, a reference to the original type seems to contain a .Count property as I would expect... so the issue is that the _accessor seems to be casting to something other than a List<>.

how does one approach this?

TIA - e!

Answer (score 0):

My first guess would be that your test class needs a reference...

`using System.Collections.Generic;`